# Amplifier MOSFET (25m - 5V)

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, orcad

I dont know how to amplify a signal of 25mV to 5V amplitud signal ((frequency of audio input cell phone)). I have this circuit so far:
[image]

Comment: You don’t seem to know what you are doing. Have you considered just using a self-contained audio amplifier IC.

Comment: Your P-mosfet M2 seems to be upside-down.

Comment: What's the nature of the source?

Answer (score 0):

Providing a voltage gain of 200 on to an 8-ohm load, linearly, with a single stage amplifier and without feedback would be rather hard. The only way I can see of approaching it is by using a transformer to match the impedance of the load.

You can start with a two stage amplifier, common-source into source-follower. That way the output impedance of your voltage amplification stage can be paired with a low-impedance output stage to match the impedance of your speaker.

Comment: Using a two stage amplifier with a common source and a source followe i have to make a current source and i have to implemented into the reality so what other avaible option you can sugest me.

Answer (score 0):

The N-channel Mosfet has +10V at its gate and its source has 2k to ground. Its drain resistance is so high that it is turned on as hard as it can and does not amplify. Why is it a high voltage, high current Mosfet?

The P-channel Mosfet has a backwards power supply (its source should have a resistor to +20V and its drain should be grounded). Its gate must be biased. Then it does nothing. Why not use another N-channel Mosfet?

Please learn about Mosfets.

Comment: i use that N- Channel MOSFET because i just have that reference, look the change that i do to the schematic to guarantee that in the gate part of the mosfet have a voltage of 5 V, in the drain part i have to garantee that have 10V and in the source part have 1 V to my amplifier works in a right way.